# How do you measure/detect Watt-Seconds?

Tags: sensor, watts

As part of a project I am working on, I am required to measure watt-seconds. I've looked this unit up online and it typically references to a camera flash.

My question is how does one measure/detect a flash to determine the watt-seconds? What kind of sensors/circuits are required to do so?

Comment: You need to clarify (in your question - not in the comments) if you are measuring power input or light output. What equipment have you got?

Comment: Ws = J. You need to measure V and I, multiply, and integrate.

Comment: @MattYoung Ws = J. it is, but that's a dangerous can of worms to open.

Comment: @Trevor How? I literally spent a year dealing with these kinds of measurements on an energy harvesting project. It's not that complicated.

Comment: @MattYoung just saying Joules is energy, it does not always have a time component....see.. I said it was dangerous to open that can ;)

Comment: @Trevor Yes, and power x time is also energy, by definition.

Comment: @MattYoung yes I know, as a subset it is. I just think mentioning it may confuse the OP.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Header asks about Ws, question is about measure/detect a flash... whatever THAT is.

Comment: Also, this type of thing needs to be very specific on how much accuracy is required.

Comment: OTOH, it could be as simple as measuring the voltage over a capacitor and plugging that into an equation. Yes, the question is far too ambiguous.

Comment: Why do you have to measure Watt seconds? Please elaborate much more about your project or your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the detector would be a phototransistor or photodiode.  Phototransistors produce a bigger output, and so are easier to work with, but are slower.  Photodiodes are faster but produce a tiny signal.

Whatever detector you use, you'll need to calibrate it - see how much current it produces for different light intensities.

You could do the measurement in the analog domain, perhaps using the current to charge a capacitor and see what voltage it charges up to - this gives you the product of brightness * time.  But the set-up is going to be very finicky.  You might be better to just hook it up to an analogue-to-digital input of a computer and just log the data.  Then add the brightnesses over a series of samples to give your brightness * time.

You're going to have to know a lot about the characteristics of the experimental setup.  Is the flash omnidirectional, or is it a beam in one direction?  Is the flash white? How far away is it?  Are there reflective walls around that could make your equipment think the flash is brighter than it really is?

Comment: Photodiodes are greatly preferable to phototransistors in any measurement application, since phototransistors have poor manufacturing control over gain (as with any BJT) and have a very strong temperature dependence. You can easily hack up a transimpedance amplifier to read out a photodiode by using a cheap op-amp, a resistor, and a capacitor on a perfboard.

Answer (score 0):

The watt-second rating of a camera flash is the watt-seconds (joules) of energy of the fully charged capacitor that provides energy to the glass tube. Energy stored in a capacitor in watt-seconds or joules is equal to 1/2 C (farads) X voltage squared. If the flash is cut off before the capacitor is fully discharged, you would need to measure the capacitor voltage and calculate the energy before and after the flash is fired.

I believe there in an instrument that can be placed in the illuminated ares to measure the effect of the flash at that point. The use of such a meter would be explained in the meter instructions. If the question is related to that, it is not about electrical engineering and thus off-topic for this site.